# Custom Login Page CSS Styles

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site, with installed theme Enfold and the MemberMouse plugin.
I have also made some signup,login pages by using Membermouse.

But my login page is not nice.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwy6b.png

I want to it make like this one or similar:https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR145.png
( reflexionyoga(dot)com/login/ )

Can someone guide me how to change CSS styles and make the changes?

Thanks

Comment: this is way too broad. I would recommend doing some research and coming back with specific issues.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219771/custom-login-page-css-styles

Comment: Bacially I want to make a nice login page like on this one: reflexionyoga(dot)com/login/

Comment: My point is you could do a google search and come up with a host of solutions. SO is most useful when you've done a piece of work and hit a wall.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Styling page you could use:

```
body{
padding-left:20px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
font-family: verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
background-color: #ACE367;
color: black;
}
p{

font-size: 15px;
margin: 10px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
a{

font-size: 15px
color: #958F81;
text-decoration: none;
}
h1{
color:#191970;
text-align: left;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
.big{
color: #191970;
font-size: 60px;
}
h2{
text-align: left;
font-size: 15px;
margin: 15px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
img{
border-radius: 8px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
ul {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top : 0;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 50px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #ACE367;
font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
.note{
color:red;
font-size:10px;
}
input, select {
width: 100%;
padding: 14px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
width: 100%;
padding: 14px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 20px;
}
form {
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 600px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
.body-cen{
padding-left: 250px;
        padding-right: 250px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        padding-top: 25px;
}
.pd{
padding-left:30px;
}
hr { 
width:100%; 
height:2px; 
background: #fff 
}
input[type=radio]{
padding-left:0;
}
p{
padding-left:10px;
}
```